# Decompile a Mac Kernel Extension?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to decompile a Mac kernel extension?

Comment: I'm more interested in what you want to do that seems to require decompilation of a Mac kernel extension.

Comment: Not Objective-C. OS X kernel modules are written in a subset of C++.

Comment: Although you will probably get answers to the contrary decompiling is not possible from C. Compilation is lossy e.g. not a 1 to 1 mapping so some tools can claim to give a program that MAY have been the C code no tool can reproduce the actual C code certainly. Debuggers are the tool to reverse engineer executables.

Comment: I'm interested too, tell me if you find out please

Comment: You can write an OS X kext in pure C.

Answer (score 2):

In theory it is possible to decompile any binary code.

Kernel extensions are a little bit tricky because
a) they're C++, so virtual methods make the code harder to follow.
b) linking happens differently in kernel extensions, so any decompiler would need be specially designed to handle kernel extensions in order to find dependencies and symbol names.

Comment: ken: kextload handles a) and b)

Comment: They're really easy to follow because many kexts are straight C and open-source.  (IOKit kexts more/less require a subset of C++.)  Furthermore, you can grab the KDK which has the symbols for nearly everything that's open-source.

Answer (score 1):

you can use gdb (as nate c suggested) to inspect the assembly code of a kernel extension. i'm not aware of any decompilers for kernel extensions specifically.

you can use the kextload tool to create a symbols file that you can load into gdb. this will let you see decoded symbol names for functions, &c. there's a crash (haha get it?) tutorial here: http://praveenmatanam.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/kext-debugging-on-mac/

why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why on earth would you question someone's curiosity?  Freedom to tinker!

Comment: I think it was more like "maybe I can give you a better answer"

Answer (score 0):

It is no problem to decompile 32bit kext's using the [hexrays decompiler](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml).

Decompiling c++ code, means you have to define your structs in the right way: when an object has virtual methods, the first item in the object will be a pointer to the object's vtable.
if you declare the vtable in IDA or hexrays as well, and make sure all the types of the function pointers are correct, hexrays will produce quite readable code.

But chances are that the parts of the kext you are interested in were written in C-like C++, and you don't need to worry about that at all.

Comment: For 32-bit only, ida demo includes the 32-bit only decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

For reversing 64-bit kexts, acquire ida pro and x64 Decompiler (any of mac/lin/win).

Also, you can usually debug a kext (without symbols) using lldb remote setup. (gdb is gone.)

If you happen to work for a large security shop, do the song-and-dance: sign an NDA, give rights to first born and just get the OSX source.

Also, here's a large list of decompilers:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers